# Como ordenar um consulta usandos todas os dados dela?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Meu problema é o seguinte, preciso ordenar os `jobs` de todas as categorias de acordo com o que é pedido em um checked.
é um site de busca de empregos, preciso ordenar os jobs mais antigos assim que o checkbox for `false`, nesse caso, quando for desmarcado.
Sabendo disso, não estou conseguindo retornar essa ordenação do lado do controller quando o checkbox for falso. Resumindo o que escrevi: Quero ordenar os jobs das categorias, porém o que estou conseguindo fazer é apenas ordenar as categorias, que não é o que quero fazer. me desculpa se ficou complicado de entender.

código do controler

```
def index
    @categories = search_jobs
end

def search_jobs
        categories = params[:jobs] != 'checked' ? JobCategory.all : JobCategory.order("id DESC")
end



private
    def job_params

    params.require(:job).permit(:company_name, :site_url,
                                :title, :description, :contact_message,
                                :location, :category_id, :days_to_expire,
                                :vacancy_completed)
end
```

Alguém sabe uma forma que posso fazer isso??

Comment: Poderia melhorar a pergunta para tentar ajudar?

Comment: Preciso ordernar somente os trabalhos(jobs) de cada categoria.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi bem a pergunta, mas em todo caso, talvez o método `sort_by` te ajude

https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/sort_by